# calloc vs memset one shows resulzs and one doesn't

Tags: c, memory, allocation

So I am trying to get deep into C, and the following is a code that tackles memory allocations, files and strings/pointers. I have tried this both using callocate and memset. callocate seems to work fine but memset isn't.
The idea of the code is as follows: I create some files, everytime a file is created its name is pushed to a list. I have a fixed number of files to keep. and after that number is exausted the oldest file is deleted everytime a new one is created.
when using **calloc**. the prints show the correct messages and my folder has the last number of files:
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // needed for malloc
#include <string.h>   // needed for strcpy
#include <unistd.h>

#define  Extension                         ".txt"
#define LOG_MIN_FILENAME_SIZE               32
#define  NBR_OF_FILES                        6

char buffer[LOG_MIN_FILENAME_SIZE];   
                                     
int timez = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int NUM_OF_EXISTING_FILES=0;


FILE *pf = NULL;
char* ListOfFiles[NBR_OF_FILES];
int status;



int main(void){
    
 for(int i=0; i<NBR_OF_FILES;i++){

ListOfFiles[i] = calloc(LOG_MIN_FILENAME_SIZE + 1, 1);




  for(int i=0; i<10;i++) { 
  
  
    pf =fopen(buffer, "w");
    sprintf(buffer, "%d""%d"Extension, minutes, timez);
    
    if(access(buffer, F_OK)==-1){
        
        NUM_OF_EXISTING_FILES++;
        fclose(pf); //closing the files is necessary
        if(NUM_OF_EXISTING_FILES >= NBR_OF_FILES){
                status = remove(ListOfFiles[0]);
                printf("removed");  
                }
        
        
        for(int i=0; i < NBR_OF_FILES-1; i++){
                strcpy(ListOfFiles[i], ListOfFiles[i+1]);// u cant use just normal assignment because it copies the head ot the pointer rather than the actual content of it
        }
    
        strcpy(ListOfFiles[NBR_OF_FILES-1], buffer);
    }
        
    timez++;
    minutes++;
    
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<NBR_OF_FILES-1; i++){
        printf("%s", ListOfFiles[i]);
    }
}
```

now the code above works as I said but once I replace the calloc line with this :

```
    (void) memset(ListOfFiles[i], 0 ,LOG_MIN_FILENAME_SIZE + 2);
 }
```

the code doesn't show anything and no files are created. What is the difference between **memset** and **calloc** and why isnt it working here for me?

Comment: calloc *allocates* zero-initialized data, while memset just sets already allocated data to a certain byte value. You cannot use memset unless the data is already allocated, it may crash your application.

Comment: `the code above works`? no way it works, [segmentation fault is all I can get](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DeepskyblueUnrulyDribbleware#main.c). Right on the line `memset(ListOfFiles[i]` - `ListOfFiles[i]` is NULL.

Comment: memset dosn't allocate memory. Int only fills it. You can use it if you call `malloc()` before (`malloc()` allocates memory but doesn't initialize it so `p=malloc(n)` + `memset(p,0,n)` is equivalent to `p=calloc(n,1)`

Comment: At no point does this code actually set `ListOfFiles` to anything but `NUL`s (incorrectly when using `memset`, correctly when `calloc`-ing). Your "list of files" has no names in it either way. I strongly suspect, in the process of trying to make a [MCVE], you removed the parts of your code that make it work at all.

Comment: @shadowranger if you try the code you will definitely see that calloc is doing the job. I am not an expert on what happens behind the code. But from the execution.,the printf of the content of ListOfValues at the end returns the correct strings.

Comment: I had inversed the functions, I am sorry everyone for the confusion. **Calloc is what works** and **memset doesn't.** I fixed the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is problematic:

```c
char* ListOfFiles[NBR_OF_FILES];
memset(ListOfFiles[0], ...);
```

`memset` expects its first argument to be a pointer to a buffer it'll modify. But `ListOfFiles[0]` is `NULL`<sup>[1]</sup>. Nothing good can come of that. Specifically, it's undefined behaviour that results in a SIGSEGV (crash) on modern general-purpose computers.

`calloc`, on the other hand, allocates a buffer and returns a pointer to it. This is indeed the correct approach.

---

1. Because `ListOfFiles` is found in static storage because it's a global. In other circumstances, it could be uninitialized, which is even worse.

Comment: Note: It could be worse. At least with `ListOfFiles` being global, it's guaranteed to be full of `NULL`s. If it were on the stack, it would be full of random stack detritus, and might conceivably work in some cases, and produce baffling errors in others.

Comment: ListOfFiles[0] is null or undefined depending on what c/c++ standard we are talking about.

Comment: @Sven Nilsson, I'm under impression that variables in static storage are initialized as if `= 0` was used. Feel free to provide details if that's not correct.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  Re "*At least with `ListOfFiles` being global, it's guaranteed to be full of `NULL`s*", yeah, I was going to avoid mentioning that to keep things simple, but I've now added a footnote.

Comment: @SvenNilsson: Does it? Both [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization) and [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) seem to guarantee that anything with static storage duration (which [includes all globals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration)) is zero-initialized, default-initialized, or some combination thereof.

Comment: C99 certainly guarantees it, but I don't think it was in the initial standard. No one uses that anymore so it does not matter much.